# adding an action link to an Html table generated by an html helper MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Htmlhelper extension method that generates an Html table from any `List<T>`

I have to add functionality to make the data from any given column the ability to be a Link.

I have created a new class that contains all the data needed to make a link

```
  public class ColumnLinkDescription
  {
    //controller name
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    //Action name
    public string Action { get; set; }
    //parameter
    public string ID { get; set; }
  }
```

i also added a method that will try to generate a link if the column has a Link description

```
    private static string TryGenerateLink<T>(HtmlHelper helper, T d, TableHeaderDetails h, string value)
    {
      if (h.Link != null)
      {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var url = urlHelper.Action(h.Link.Controller,
        h.Link.Action,
        new { id = d.GetType().GetProperty(h.Link.ID) });
        value= url;
      }
      return value;
    }
```

this ties into my Table maker in the following way:

```
      value= ((d.GetType().GetProperty(h.Name).GetValue(d, null)) ?? "").ToString();
      td.InnerHtml = TryGenerateLink<T>(helper, d, h, value);
      tr.InnerHtml += td.ToString();
```

I tried it out but the output was:

```
<td class=" ">/ActionTest/ControllerTest/Int32%20ArticleCode</td>
```

using the definition:

```
new ColumnLinkDescription{Controller = "ControllerTest", Action="ActionTest", ID="ArticleCode"}
```

It looks like I should be using a differnet approach than urlHelper.Action and I am having a tough time obtaining the value of ArticleCode and adding that as a parameter to the link.

EDIT1:

I got the value of the parameter working by a simple modification in TryGenerateLink()

```
var url = urlHelper.Action(h.Link.Controller, h.Link.Action, new { id = d.GetType().GetProperty(h.Link.ID).GetValue(d,null) });
```

Output:

```
<td class=" ">/ActionTest/ControllerTest/96776</td>
```

so the only issue remaining is the correct generation of a hyperlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to be using `UrlHelper` for this, because as you've already noticed, `UrlHelper.Action` will create a relative URL but not the anchor tag.  What you really want to be doing is making use of `HtmlHelper`.  That way, you can use `helper.ActionLink` to build the link for you.